# Will CallableStatement.close() cause performance issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, ibm-midrange

I have a question about performance.

The app I work on is a Spring MVC app (v3.2.9). It's hosted on a WebSphere Application Server (v8.5.5). It is connected to an AS400 DB2 system (driver is  JTOpen v9.1). My app calls a stored procedure on an IBM AS400 system. It is being called using Spring's JdbcTemplate.execute method. Here's the code:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(new CallableStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{CALL XXXXXXSP ( ?, ? )}");
            cs.setString(1, xxx);
            cs.setString(2, xxx);
            return cs;
        }
    }, 
    new CallableStatementCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public String doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            cs.execute();
            return null;
        }
    });
```

We're running into some issues where the calling of this procedure occasionally throws an error "[SQL0501] Cursor C1 not open" After turning up the logging and reviewing, it looks like this error only happens when the app attempts to re-use a CallableStatement. The respective cursor was closed the last time this CallableStatement was used, which results in the error (I'm not 100% sure if this re-use is expected behavior or not). The error happens around 20 times per day, which is a relatively low percentage as this application has much higher traffic.

My question is, will adding `cs.close();` to the code after `cs.execute();` cause a deterioration in the performance of the code?

Comment: the problem is in the program you are calling on the AS400.  You will have to fix it on the AS400.  I see these in the wild with close statement is not executed when no records are found, no initial commit for commitment control.  I also see in the wild not checking if the open was successful so the fetch fails.  Add code to check the open statement.  If the open fails issue a close statement then another open statement.

Comment: @danny117 thank you for the advice, just want to clarify... The open statement and close statement that you are referring to would be in the program on the AS400, not the Java code, is that correct?

Comment: Yes it looks like as400 coding problem.     I'm assuming close is for close cursor.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should call close() method to close statement ,as it release resources. there is no any issue with this.

But JdbcTemplate close statement for you , so do not need it.

here is what JdbcTemplate  do at the end of execution `execute(CallableStatementCreator csc, CallableStatementCallback<T> action)` method :

```
JdbcUtils.closeStatement(cs);
DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
```

And from CallableStatementCallback api :

```
 doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException ,DataAccessException
```

> Gets called by JdbcTemplate.execute with an active JDBC
>   CallableStatement. Does not need to care about closing the Statement
>   or the Connection, or about handling transactions: this will all be
>   handled by Spring's JdbcTemplate. **NOTE:** Any ResultSets opened should
>   be closed in finally blocks within the callback implementation. Spring
>   will close the Statement object after the callback returned, but this
>   does not necessarily imply that the ResultSet resources will be
>   closed: the Statement objects might get pooled by the connection pool,
>   with close calls only returning the object to the pool but not
>   physically closing the resources.

Comment: It seems like any result sets explicitly opened by the stored procedure need to be closed by the client.  I'm not sure where in the framework that is supposed to happen.  If the result sets isn't supposed to be returned to the caller, then the stored procedure should have closed the result set.  Also, since cursor names need to be unique in a job, the stored procedure should use a more specific name than C1 for the cursor name.